# App Access token gets denied

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I got an issue with the debug_token option in the Graph Api.
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug) and [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) it states that a call like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token to check}&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

should give me back information about the token I query.

If I use a Admin-User token in the Graph Api Explorer it works fine but not for the App Access Token.

Comment: Works fine for me, even in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: I used the app token button in the Explorer and provided an User-Token I requested earlier and it keeps responding that I need to provide a valid token.

Comment: _“and provided an User-Token I requested earlier”_ – what now, I thought you wanted to check your app access token?